Calling another Makefile and keep its prerequistite
I have a complicated project, which has several submodules in it. Each submodule has its own Makefile and generates its own target.
Top project need submodule's target. The makefile of submodule may be very complicated and prerequisite is not easy to get.
I expect that, when I modified submodule's source code and make the top project, the submodule could be rebuild automatically. How should I write my Makefile for top project?
To simplify the discussion, let's assume the project is as follow:
.
├── Makefile
├── build
│   └── finial_target
├── submodule
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   │   └── submodule_target
│   └── src_2
└── src_1


finial_target is target of ./Makefile and need src_1 and submodule_target.
submodule is target of ./submodule/Makefile and need src_2.

I thought of a solution:
build/finial_target: src_1 submodule/build/submodule_target
    # something

submodule/build/submodule_target: build-submodule

.PHONY: build-submodule
build-submodule:
    $(MAKE) -C submodule

But I don't know whether this is best practice. Please give some advice.
Thanks a lot.

Why do you need the phony build-submodule target at all? It seems like the submodule/build/submodule_target target could run the $(MAKE) -C submodule command itself.

On the question of whether it is a good idea to have one Makefile invoke another, there are many schools of thought. One is Peter Miller's essay Recursive Make Considered Harmful.

@NickODell Because once submodule/build/submodule_target is generated, Makefile always considers submodule_target as the latest (since it has no prerequisites), $(MAKE) -C submodule won't execute again.


If you tell Make about the submodule's dependencies, then it will rebuild the submodule when necessary. Of course, then you'd have to maintain the list of dependencies in two Makefiles. 2) You could also mark submodule/build/submodule_target as phony, in which case it would execute the recursive make whether or not the submodule needs to be rebuilt.


@NickODell I didn't think of that... "2)" might be what I want. Thanks a lot.
